# R: Count instances where row value is within range of other row values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with >200,000 rows and two columns, Group and Value.  Group contains a string and Value contains positive integers.  All rows are unique (i.e. For a given Group, each Value entry is present only once).  I want to `group_by(Group)` and then determine the number of instances where a row has a Value which is ≤5 from other row Values (see example).

For instance, if a row had a Group "A" and had a Value of "25", we would search all rows that have Group "A" to determine if any have Values that fall between 20 and 30. If any such rows existed, add a value of 1 to the Count for Group "A", then proceed to the next row.

I provided a simplified example with only 7 rows and a code that uses `purrr` to count the number of instances correctly.  However, it is extremely slow to run when applied to a dataframe with 200,000 rows.

Is there a way to do this that is less computationally taxing?

```
data <- data.frame(Group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
                   Value = c(1, 2, 3, 9, 15, 17, 19))

count_pairs <- function(positions) {
  combn(positions, 2, function(x) abs(x[1] - x[2]) < 5) %>% sum
}

result <- data %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarise(Count = count_pairs(Value))
```

```
> print(result)
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  Group Count
  <chr> <int>
1 A         3
2 B         3
```

Comment: I have difficulties to understand *determine the number of instances where a row has a Value which is ≤5 from other row Values*. Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: Sure - I updated my post with a bit more clarification.

Comment: I think the results depends on the order of the observations then. Is this intentional?

Comment: Not intentional.  I should probably arrange by Value and then by Group if only searching rows before/after.  Or the code would need to search all rows (not just neighboring).  All rows are unique - adding that information to the original post.

Comment: @JVGen It sounds like what you need is a fast window function. Check out data.table's [`foverlaps`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.14.10/topics/foverlaps) - I did some geospatial anaylsis with it a couple of years ago and it should be able to get the job done

Comment: Where are you using `purrr`? Your question says "≤5" yet your code is `< 5`, which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We aren't looking to count how many `Value`s are within 5 of each `Value`, we're looking to see *if* any other values match "this" value, and then count the occurrences for each group. Using sorted values takes a lot of the math out of it and allows us to determine things much faster.

Original data:

```r
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  arrange(Value) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarize(
    Count = sum((Value - lag(Value)) < 5 | (lead(Value) - Value) < 5, na.rm = TRUE)
  )
# # A tibble: 2 × 2
#   Group Count
#   <chr> <int>
# 1 A         3
# 2 B         3
```

Larger data borrowed from ThomasIsCoding:

```r
set.seed(1701)
data <- tibble(
    Group = sample(LETTERS, size = 200000, replace = TRUE),
    Value = sample(1:100, size = 200000, replace = TRUE)
)
data
# # A tibble: 200,000 × 2
#    Group Value
#    <chr> <int>
#  1 H        91
#  2 O        27
#  3 W        70
#  4 G        33
#  5 D        42
#  6 F        70
#  7 X        66
#  8 X        37
#  9 X        68
# 10 D        45
# # ℹ 199,990 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Rerunning the `dplyr` approach:

```r
data %>%
  arrange(Value) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarize(Count = sum((Value - lag(Value)) < 5 | (lead(Value) - Value) < 5, na.rm = TRUE))
# # A tibble: 26 × 2
#    Group Count
#    <chr> <int>
#  1 A      7819
#  2 B      7541
#  3 C      7783
#  4 D      7574
#  5 E      7662
#  6 F      7850
#  7 G      7727
#  8 H      7710
#  9 I      7515
# 10 J      7707
# # ℹ 16 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

I suggest that `data.table` might be faster for this,

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
setorder(data, Group, Value) # just Value would be fine too
data[, sum(Value - lag(Value) < 5 | lead(Value) - Value < 5, na.rm = TRUE), by = "Group"]
#      Group    V1
#     <char> <int>
#  1:      A  7819
#  2:      B  7541
#  3:      C  7783
#  4:      D  7574
#  5:      E  7662
#  6:      F  7850
#  7:      G  7727
#  8:      H  7710
#  9:      I  7515
# 10:      J  7707
# ---             
# 17:      Q  7560
# 18:      R  7614
# 19:      S  7771
# 20:      T  7833
# 21:      U  7700
# 22:      V  7770
# 23:      W  7730
# 24:      X  7672
# 25:      Y  7648
# 26:      Z  7808
```

Both of those are under 1 second operation, and indeed their relative performance is good and slightly favors `data.table`:

```r
bench::mark(
dplyr = data %>%
    arrange(Value) %>%
    group_by(Group) %>%
    summarize(Count = sum((Value - lag(Value)) < 5 | (lead(Value) - Value) < 5, na.rm = TRUE)),
  data.table = data[, sum(Value - lag(Value) < 5 | lead(Value) - Value < 5, na.rm = TRUE), by = "Group"],
  check = FALSE, min_iterations = 100)
# # A tibble: 2 × 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory time             gc                
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list> <list>           <list>            
# 1 dplyr        23.2ms   25.8ms      37.4        NA    0.763    98     2      2.62s <NULL> <NULL> <bench_tm [100]> <tibble [100 × 3]>
# 2 data.table   13.2ms     19ms      53.1        NA    0       100     0      1.88s <NULL> <NULL> <bench_tm [100]> <tibble [100 × 3]>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I tested this against my (much slower) code and I get the same result.  Yours completes within seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You want to separate the operations which need to be done by group, and the operations that can be done on a vector all at once. Here is an example using the tidyverse.

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1701)

data <- tibble(
  Group = sample(LETTERS, size = 200000, replace = TRUE),
  Value = sample(1:200000, size = 200000, replace = FALSE)
)

data |> 
  arrange(Group, Value) |> 
  # Only do this part by group
  mutate(value_prev = lag(Value), 
         value_next = lead(Value),
         .by = Group) |> 
  # Vectorised operations for calculating the difference
  mutate(prev_diff = Value - value_prev, 
         next_diff = value_next - Value,
         min_diff = pmin(prev_diff, next_diff, na.rm = TRUE)) |> 
  filter(min_diff <= 5) |> 
  # Summarise by group again
  summarise(Count = n(),
            .by = Group)
```

Finishing in less than a second:

```
# A tibble: 26 × 2
   Group Count
   <chr> <int>
 1 A      2475
 2 B      2473
 3 C      2359
 4 D      2426
 5 E      2436
 6 F      2563
 7 G      2438
 8 H      2532
 9 I      2636
10 J      2413
# … with 16 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: I think your approaches target different things. Does the second work for >200k rows? Try with `data = data.frame(Group = sample(c("A", "B"), 2e5, replace = TRUE), Value = sample(1L:50L, 2e5, replace = TRUE)); data = data[order(data$Group, data$Value), ]`

Comment: I changed the example to a bigger dataset, and now the second solution indeed takes too long, but the first solution remains fast. Removed the second approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sequence` within `summarise`

```
data %>%
    group_by(Group) %>%
    summarise(Count = {
        u <- seq_len(n() - 1)
        v <- rev(u)
        p <- rep(u, v)
        q <- sequence(v, 1 + u)
        sum(abs(Value[p] - Value[q]) < 5)
    })
```

which gives

```
  Group Count
1     A     3
2     B     3
```

Comment: FYI, on my machine this results in *Error in `summarise()`:
ℹ In argument: `Count = sum(dist(Value) < 5)`.
ℹ In group 1: `Group = "A"`.
Caused by error:
! vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.* Tried with `data = data.frame(Group = sample(c("A", "B"), 2e5, replace = TRUE),
                  Value = sample(1L:50L, 2e5, replace = TRUE)); data = data[order(data$Group, data$Value), ]`

Comment: @Friede aha, that's good point. I just found that `dist` would incur some logic error, so I updated it with `sequence`.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Hah, I just posted an approach based on your answer to another question :)

Comment: I just tried this, but it appears to run out of memory?  `Error in `summarise()`:
ℹ In argument: `Count = { ... }`.
ℹ In group 4: `Group = "D"`.
Caused by error:
! vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)`